# Traefik with custom config on ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, traefik

How can I upload an image of the traefik on ECS with the configuration file embedded?

```
docker run -d -p 8080: 8080 -p 80:80 \
-v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
traefik: v1.7
```

How to reproduce `-v $PWD /traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml` on ECS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to do a Bind Mount and 'mountPoints' in a ContainerDefinition within ECS task definition is equivalent of Docker Bind mounts:

```
"volumes": [
    {
      "name": "traefikroot",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/traefikroot"
      }
    }
  ]
```

---

```
  "mountPoints": [
    {
      "sourceVolume": "traefikroot",
      "containerPath": "/etc/traefik"
    }
  ]
```

Any files at '/traefikroot' will be presented to container at '/etc/traefik'.

Please see detailed example here:
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html#bind-mount-examples